# refactor transaction handling code in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using php 5.3.3 and developing a MVC webapp using codeigniter. The code I am trying to refactor is basically bunch of:

```
$this->db->trans_start();
    // do some db updates
    $this->db->update(...);
    $this->db->update(...);
$this->db->trans_complete();

if ( $this->db->trans_status() == FALSE ) {
    $this->handle_db_error();
}
```

so I have a few of the above code scatter around in my model classes. I would like to refactor the transaction handling part out of the models and stay DRY.

I thought I could using closure like the following:

```
// in parent CI_Model class 
class MY_Model extends CI_Model {
  public function txn_wrap($closure) {
    $this->db->trans_start();
    $closure();
    $this->db->trans_complete();
    if ( $this->db->trans_status() == FALSE ) {
        $this->handle_db_error();
    }
  }

// in child model class

 class Blog_model extends MY_Model {
   protected $_table = 'app_blog';

   public function get($id) {
     $instance = $this;
     $closure = function() use($instance, $id) { 
        // do some db updates
        $instance->db->update($instance->_table, array('title' => 'bla'), array('id' => $id));
     };
     $this->txn_wrap($closure);
   }
```

That doesn't work and gives me `"PHP Fatal error:  Using $this when not in object context"`. So I guess using of $this usage is not supported in 5.3.

Now failing of using closure, What else can I do?

**UPDATE:**  now I am getting `Undefined property: App_Blog::$_table` where App_About is the controller which calls the get() function in Blog_model. I have tried `function() use($instance, , $instance->_table, $id)` but php complains about the syntax.. Now this closure thing doesn't appears give me as much benefits as I thought..

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closure is not a method of your child model class, so you cannot access the instance. You will need to provide it to the closure:

```
$instance = $this;
$table = $this->_table;
$update_db_closure = function() use ($instance, $table) {
    // do some db updates
    $instance->db->update($table, ...);
    $instance->db->update($table, ...);
};
```

The `$this->_table` property is `protected`, thus you won't be able to access it inside the closure, so you need to pass a copy of it.

Comment: This is incredibly weird, since `$this` is not referenced in the closure _at all_. Are you sure you're getting the same error? Where are you getting it exactly?

Comment: well. $instance is a copy of $this. maybe that's not allowed either? I have updated my question but basically just replace `function()` to `function() use ($instance)` and add some context.

Comment: You have updated it to add `use ($instance)`, but you've forgotten to replace `$this` inside the closure with `$instance`, that's why you keep getting the error.

Comment: sigh, I did change that one but forgot another. anyway, I am getting a new error and have updated my question. thanks for sticking this one with me.

Comment: thanks. should have thought of that! Now that's 6 lines of refactoring of another 6 lines of code. and the variable passing to use() is vary in different situation and the benefit of closure now isn't attractive anymore :-(